# How to round float number to N decimal places precisely [JAVA]

Tags: java

What I would like to do is a method to round float number to N decimal places (N will be given in stdin), do some math operation with it and then print the result. I found this:

```
   public BigDecimal round(float number, int decimal){
   BigDecimal obj = new BigDecimal(number).setScale(decimal, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
   return obj;
```

Which works pretty well, but not when number N (int decimal in this method) is high. For example: x = -10, y = -11.8814, N = 8 and it prints this:

```
-10.00000000 + -11.88140011 = -21.88140106
```

And this is what I would want:

```
-10.00000000 + -11.88140000 = -21.88140000
```

Thanks everybody for suggestions :)

Comment: how do you print those values? you know if you convert BigDecimal back to float you lose precision right?

Comment: How did you input `y` ? provide a [mcve] please

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest thing to do is multiply your numbers by 10^N and use round() to turn them into integers. Run your math and then divide them back down

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = -10.0;
        double b = -11.88140011;
        int n = 4;
        long total = round(a, n) + round(b, n);

        System.out.println(String.format("%.8f%n", total * Math.pow(10, -1*n)));
    }

    static Long round(double number, int decimal) {
        return Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, decimal));
    }
```

Comment: It works perfect! Unfortunately not on operation " * ". But I hope I'll work that out soon :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `float` representation of 11.88140000 with all 8 decimal places intact, so at the moment you pass that number to your method regardless of the implementation it has no chance to return the wanted result, see [article for float on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format):

> ... the total precision is 24 bits (equivalent to log10(224) ≈ 7.225 decimal digits)

And that precision is including all digits, not only those after the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already has an answer, but to understand the problem float vs. decimal better, there is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) about the problem explaining it a bit more in depth (same for every programming language):

Just for completeness: 0.3 would be exactly stored as it is in a BigDecimal. In float (due to it's binary nature), it would be stored as 0.30000001192092896. You instantiate your BigDecimal using a float and directly step into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the answer. I didn't use function *round* I only printed the numbers with results:

`System.out.printf("%." + n + "f + %." + n + "f = %." + n + "f\n", a, b, a + b);`

Which I tried before I posted this question, BUT I used float and haven't tried using double (with function *nextDouble()* for scanning). So, double was the answer.

Thanks for your suggestions! :))